# DELETE and PUT all default to GET in symfony

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony

I am facing a serious challenge with my application. DELETE and PUT works perfectly in the localhost but when I deploy to a server they all default to GET. As a  result, I get 400 status code response. I am using angularJS and symfony.

Below are my codes

Angular:

```
    return t.delete("projects/" + e.id).success(function() {
    for (var t = 0; t < c.all.length; t++) c.all[t].id == e.id &&     c.all.splice(t, 1)
    }).error(function(e) {
    alertify.log(e, "error", 2e3)
    });
```

Symfony Router:

```
    $app->delete('/projects/{id}', "projects.controller:delete")-  >before($loggedInFilter);
```

Comment: I have never heard of this happening before. How do you know your DELETE and PUT requests are being received at GET requests?

Comment: You haven't given near enough information to debug this. For instance it seems older versions of symfony suffer from a bug close to this. What version of symfony are you using. What does the networking tab in your browser show when angularjs  makes a request. What is the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] when a request is made?

Comment: `Symfony` or more likely `Silex`?

Comment: Which browser? Some old browsers don't support PUT and DELETE

Comment: @mschuett - $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] returns GET while the networking tab shows DELETE and PUT for related actions

Comment: @naneri - I am using Silex, a lightweight version of symfony